# Geometric interpretation of the multiplication of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces

I've always been taught that one way to look at complex numbers is as a Cartesian space, where the *real* part is the $x$ component and the *imaginary* part is the $y$ component.

In this sense, these complex numbers are like vectors, and they can be added geometrically like normal vectors can.

However, is there a geometric interpretation for the multiplication of two complex numbers?

I tried out two test ones, $3+i$ and $-2+3i$, which multiply to $-9+7i$.  But no geometrical significance seems to be found.

Is there a geometric significance for the multiplication of complex numbers?

Comment: Good answers are also found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Geometric_interpretation_of_the_operations, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Operations_in_polar_form

Comment: ...and (of course) in Needhams _Visual Complex Analysis_, in particular Figure [6] on page 9: http://books.google.com/books?id=ogz5FjmiqlQC&lpg=PP1&dq=visual%20complex%20analysis&pg=PA9

Comment: I found this to be a nice visualization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Suppose we multiply the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$. If these numbers are written in the polar form as $r_1 e^{i \theta_1}$ and $r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$, the product will be $r_1 r_2 e^{i (\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$. Equivalently, we are stretching the first complex number $z_1$ by a factor equal to the magnitude of the second complex number $z_2$ and then rotating the stretched $z_1$ counter-clockwise by an angle $\theta_2$ to arrive at the product. There are several websites that expand upon this intuition with graphics and more explanation. See this site for example - http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Geometric_multiplication.htm

Comment: As soon as you said $r_1 e^{i\theta_1} * r_2 e^{i\theta_2} $, it all made sense.  Thanks :)  Even looking at my crudely drawn vectors it looks to be exactly that.

Answer (score 20):

Add the angles and multiply the lengths.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a simple geometric meaning, but you need to convert to the polar form of the complex numbers to see it clearly.  $3+i$ has magnitude $\sqrt{10}$ and angle about $18^\circ$;
$-2+3i$ has magnitude $\sqrt{13}$ and angle about $124^\circ$.
Multiplication of the complex numbers multiplies the two magnitudes, resulting in $\sqrt{130}$,
and adds the two angles, $142^\circ$.
In other words, you can view the second number as scaling and rotating the first (or the first scaling and rotating the second).