# What would be geometrically analogous to adding or multplying points on the plane $\mathbb R^2$? ( On complex numbers).

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, soft-question, definition

Why not a complete  duplicate ( though a partial one)  : This question deals both with multiplication of complex numbers,and with addition;  hence , with the general  idea of performing a binary operation on ordered pairs of reals. So, it is a bit more general as another post ( linked below) , and , as such, may be useful for complex numbers beginners, like me.

[Geometric interpretation of the multiplication of complex numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/geometric-interpretation-of-the-multiplication-of-complex-numbers)

---

- Complex numbers are defined as elements of $\mathbb R^2$, that is, ordered pairs of real numbers.
- So, in a way, binary operations on complex numbers - such as addition or multiplication -  are similar to adding or multiplicating points.
- Can these operations be represented as movements in the real plane, in the same way as addition of integers is represented, at the basic level, as a movement on a line , or rather, on a series of aligned dots.
- Maybe adding two complex numbers is analogous to moving from one point to another?
- But I can't imagin to what movement could correspond multiplying two complex numbers.

Note : in comments, a link to a very helpful video by 3Blue1Brown.

Comment: I don't know why this got a -1, it's a fine question.

Comment: Have you thought about the [polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) of complex numbers?

Comment: That said, [it's a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/geometric-interpretation-of-the-multiplication-of-complex-numbers). Briefly, adding corresponds to summing the position vectors, and multiplication corresponds to multiplying magnitudes and addiing rotational angles (think about polar form $re^{i\theta}$ ...).

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ) may provide some insight. The part from about 6:00 is relevant to your question, though the preceding part may be useful to watch as well.

Comment: Multiplying by a real number corresponds to a scaling; multiplying by $i$ corresponds to a $90^\circ$ rotation

Comment: Thanks for all these answers. ( New to complex numbers, I'll search in all these directions).

Comment: @Servaes. Actually, very useful video. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplication by a non-zero complex number can be seen as the composition of a rotation (around $0$) with a homothety (with respect to $0$). That can be seen in the polar representation of complex numbers: if $z=\rho\bigl(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i\bigr)$, then multiplication of $w$ by $z$ is the same thing as rotating $w$ clockwise by an angle of $\theta$ radians, followed by a homothety with ratio $\rho$. Or you can do the homothety first and the rotation after. The result will be the same.